# Do functions not wait for a finish in execution of line before they go on to the next line

Tags: javascript, function, var

I am used to programming in python and am trying to learn javascript. I want the application to work on chrome so dont care to make it cross-browser. I also want to write it without using jquery or another library - since I am just learning javascript.

My general problem is that very often the function calls seem like they are "skipped". I am using firebug and dont see any errors on the console. So If I have two calls calls right after each other in a function

```
mydict_user_values = return_dict_of_user_names()
alert("I HAVE USER VALUES " + mydict_user_values.length) 
// This next line gets called sometimes before the previous line so the values in the table filled in by next line are blank even though the dictionary above has the correct length
fill_user_name_values_into_table(mydict_user_values)
```

I am used to python and dont understand whats going on. Sorry for an abstract question , but there is something fundamental about javascript that I am not getting.

edited: -6 points in one day. I am quite shocked!. I know there are some serious newbie errors in my code: Which I have put here in all its newbie badness.

https://github.com/harijay/gridzilla_web

My Typical functions:

```
function return_dict_of_user_names()
{
   var my_new_dict 
   var my_user_names = document.getElementsByClassName("my_users");
   for (var i = 0; i <= my_user_names.length ; i++){
      var a_num  = document.getElementById("user_number_" + i).value
      var a_name = document.getElementById("user_name_" + i).value
      my_new_dict[i] = [a_num,a_name]
   }
   return my_new_dict
}
```

I then have other javascript functions that take these values and populate another part of the same page.

```
function fill_user_names_into_div(mydict){
   var my_username_dict = mydict;
   //Javascript code to fill in the values by lines like
   my_fillable_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("user_table_fancy_entry")
   for (var i = 0 ; i <= my_fillable_elements.length ; i++){
      document.getElementById("usertable_user_number_" + i).value = my_username_dict[1][1]
   }
```

Comment: Nope, Javascript statements are executed synchronously. You haven't really shown us a demonstrable problem, so I don't think that this can be answered.

Comment: Hey guys.  Not so quick to close this.  There are javascript errors in the code provided that we can help them fix.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak and jfriend00 for your patience. -3 points already for what I thought was a well posed question. I guess even saying "help my code doesnt work" would have gotten a less harsh reaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript statements are executed synchronously.  I think you have some javascript errors that is probably halting execution in some places.  You should be looking in an javascript error console or a debug console to see where you have javascript errors.  For example, in this function:

```
function return_dict_of_user_names()
{
   var my_new_dict 
   var my_user_names = document.getElementsByClassName("my_users");
   for (var i = 0; i <= my_user_names.length ; i++){
      var a_num  = document.getElementById("user_number_" + i).value
      var a_name = document.getElementById("user_name_" + i).value
      my_new_dict[i] = [a_num,a_name]
   }
   return my_new_dict
}
```

You have to initialize my_new_dict to an array before using it as such like this:

```
function return_dict_of_user_names()
{
   var my_new_dict = [];   // initialize to empty array
   var my_user_names = document.getElementsByClassName("my_users");
   for (var i = 0; i < my_user_names.length ; i++) {
      var temp = [];
      temp.push(document.getElementById("user_number_" + i).value);
      temp.push(document.getElementById("user_name_" + i).value);
      my_new_dict.push(temp);
   }
   return my_new_dict;
}
```

Also, javascript statements should end with a semicolon and I'd recommend using `.push()` to add an item onto the end of an array.

Comment: I am using firebug and the chrome developer tools (CTRL+Shift+I). The reason I resorted to a question here is that after spending a few hours with the code , I could not understand why there were no errors in the firebug console. I had alert statements in my code which were not getting called everytime- confounding the troubleshooting.

Comment: @harijay - you must be missing something in the Chrome console because when I make a working version of your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Z8Dvm/, I see an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined` which is caused because you didn't initialize my_new_dict to an empty array.  It's all right there in the Chrome console.

Comment: Thanks a tonne jfriend00. I see some errors in my real code now which all may be resulting from lookups for array elements in empty dicts. I posted a link to my code above. But you have already been a great help. Also thanks for the pointer to jsFiddle